# Crawling Only SharePoint SubSite

Tags: enterprise-search

I have a sitecollection-Test and subsite Test1. I want to crawl only subsite leaving out sitecollection using crawl rules.
how to give the crawl rules.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I can't tell if you're wanting to crawl just one specific subsite or if you're wanting to crawl all subsites in the collection, without crawling the top level. Can you add that detail to your question, please?

Comment: Also, please include which version of SharePoint you're referring to. 2013 and 2010 can be quite different.

Comment: I am using SP2013. As of now i have only one site collection and one subsite. So i want to crawl just the subsite.

Comment: Why not use security rather than crawl rules?